# Overlay world map with server locations and server status. Concept ideas

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dictionary, orm

We are developing a number of "current status" plugins for our system. These plugins monitor different elements on our servers.

One of the end goals that has been identified is that we should have a world map showing the locations of all our servers and the current status of the server(Green, Orange, Red circles) as indicated by these plugins.

Clicking on a colored circle should link the user to detail about this location.

Can anyone give some insight on what route i should take with displaying the map and status circles. Take into account this map should be zoomable as large cities will have a lot of servers.

The ability to easily add new locations to the map is important. Id like it to be by supplying the locations longitude and latitude.

The configuration utility that i would like this added to is written in C# WinForms. If its significantly easier/better id be happy creating a separate utility in WPF. We don't want to use any paid 3rd party services.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **Bing Maps WPF Control**, which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx)

That will supply you with the ability to create map pointers based on the **Latitude**, and **Longitude**.

As for the traffic light requirement, you can simply create a new [Custom Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx), inheriting from `Pushpin`, then, using a `Style`, you can define how the traffic light will *look* based on the status of the server.

Comment: But note that using the Bing Maps Control is not free (at least not for commercial desktop applications). However, there are free alternatives with similar functionality.